Bazel absolute path inclusion issue (MacOS, arm)
I'm trying to build a proto_library, but this error occurred
(absolute path inclusion(s) found in rule ...)

I thought it might be an issue with finding the Xcode toolchain, but the files listed in the error actually exist. However, one thing that seems suspicious is that the SDK path confirmed through xcrun is as follows: (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.5.sdk).
The toolchain that Bazel seems to be identifying is this one, but I’m not sure how to use this information properly.

This is my BUILD file
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_descriptor_set", "proto_library")
load("@rules_proto_grpc//go:defs.bzl", "go_grpc_library", "go_proto_library")

proto_library(
    name = "my_proto",
    srcs = [
        "my.proto",
    ],
)

go_proto_library(
    name = "my_go_proto",
    importpath = "github.com/mypath/my_go_proto",
    protos = [
        ":my_proto",
    ],
)

